# Rails stop logging when allow_concurrency = true

Tags: multithreading, logging, concurrency, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

I'm using Rails 4.0 with Puma multi-thread server.

I had to enable "allow_concurrency = true" even in development environment because I used ActionController::Live implementing some long-pulling EventSource.

But once multi-thread enabled, Rails stop logging.. so Log file only have first page request, and have nothing after that. (STDOUT is the same)

I think either Rails.logger lost it's reference in different thread, or log file is locked by one thread and others just don't have access.

I googled it for few hours but could find any answer or similar question yet.

Answer (score 5):

Just figured out the problem.
It was because of 'quiet_assets' gem.

Comment: I'm not sure why that gem would cause this issue, but works for me as well.